# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'cURL_Exception' when using AWS EC2 APIs

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, wamp

I am trying to work something out with Amazon Web Service APIs on WAMP.I just started working on AWS 2 hours ago and I came across these error constantly:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'cURL_Exception' with message '.../sdk-1.5.15/lib/requestcore/requestcore.class.php' on line 843

and

> cURL_Exception: cURL resource: Resource id #13; cURL error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed (cURL error code 60). See http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html for an explanation of error codes.

I think it means my cURL certificate has expired.So I went to cURL official website and downloaded the newest SSL certificate PEM format file.Then I converted it and placed in C:/Windows.

Then it turns out that it didn't work.I have to turn off cURL verification which is definitely not a good idea.

The whole php script I wrote is below:

```
 <?php
 include 'aws-sdk-for-php/sdk-1.5.15/sdk.class.php';
 $ec2 = new AmazonEC2();
 $response = $ec2->describe_availability_zones(); 
 ?>
```

Any thoughts...?

Comment: did you try AWS SDK 2? Did it improve things? We're having elevated volume of errors of this kind on v1.5.7...curious if it make a difference for you.

Answer (score 0):

The newly-released [AWS SDK for PHP 2](http://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php) does a much better job of handling transient SSL errors.